# Protected Questions

Tags: discussion

My question refers to this portion of the Protected Question guides:

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question.
>   However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check,
>   so you must have earned 10 or more reputation on that specific site to
>   answer a protected question.

Even with the association bonus not factored in, is 10 really restrictive enough to have an impact?  Has the community considered raising it to say 100?

UPDATED:  I think the main benefit of Protecting a question is to stop anonymous answers.  Thoughts?

Comment: Probably worth you looking at the equivalent post on meta.se - I would post the link but am not on a useful device right now. This has been discussed to death

Comment: @RoryAlsop I will try to find it as well.  Is this feature and the limit stack wide, or can it be set site by site.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I found this one: [Why do protected questions only require 10 reputation to answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100987/why-do-protected-questions-only-require-10-reputation-to-answer)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's not specific to the Workplace and should be raised on main [meta.se] instead.

Comment: @Lilienthal Can you move it or do I re ask?

Comment: @MisterPositive In either case I think it's likely to be marked as a duplicate of the one I linked.

Comment: Yeah good point.  And I found the real benefit is to prevent anonymous postings

Comment: It's actually ok to ask here even if it could also be asked on MSE.  It sounds like you've found your answer (there) anyway, but just for future reference, you can ask questions here or there.  More people will see them there.